# Deadlock in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I'm using lambda to transfer data from s3 to redshift through copy command. Now I have files coming every hour to s3 bucket and one file transfer took more than hour and while other file landed to s3 bucket and now there is deadlock, so what all possible options I can apply to remove it and to make the process more efficient ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Redshift supports parallel COPY, which allows you to load data from multiple files in parallel. This can significantly reduce the time it takes to load data from S3 to Redshift, especially if you have a large number of files or if the files are large in size.
2. Use a larger number of compute nodes: If you have a larger number of compute nodes, the COPY process can be faster and can reduce deadlock because it can be parallelized across more nodes.

You can try any of this if not yet.